# Разширение Chrome. эмуляция клика мишкой

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Подскажите, пожалуйста, функцию с помощу которой можно эмулировать клик мышкой в хроме с помощу собственного разширения. new Event("click") не подходит, надо что бы эмуляция происходила на уровне браузера, и сайт на котором наше разширение будет эмулировать клик не смог определить был ли этот клик следан по настоящему мишкой или эмулирован разширением.

Comment: К счастью, такое невозможно)

Comment: но может все таки есть какие то способы. может написать на с++ приложение, которое будет работать на Windows, как автокликер, но только что бы не быть зависимым от положения окна в браузере, как то  связать десктопную програму и браузер, только не визуально. или может еще какие то способы есть?

Comment: Ну раз так, то, конечно, есть. Можете сделать манипулятор по типу руки, прикрутить к нему камеру, потом анализ изображения с камеры, потом робот программка будет управлять манипулятором и кликать мышкой. А можно нанять низкооплачиваемого работника, который за 1$ в день будет вам кликать)

Comment: А если хотите писать на С++ программу, то задавайте новый вопрос, указывайте в метках С++. Может, вам помогут. Но на js такого не сделать.